# Is there any way to "reroute" an authenticated SOCKS server to a non-authenticated local port, similar to SSH's -D flag?

Tags: authentication, ssh, proxy, socks

So with OpenSSH, you can do `ssh -D PORT user@ip` to open a local SOCKS server at that port.

I'm working on an application that isn't able to support SOCKS authentication, but I'd like to connect to a SOCKS server that requires authentication (user&pass). I'm thinking that a good option would be to do something similar to the `ssh` command where I can open a SOCKS server locally, except instead of linking it to an ssh daemon it's just directly forwarding to a remote authenticated SOCKS server. Is there any tool that can let me do this?

An example of what I mean:

1. There is a SOCKS server at SOME_IP. It requires SOME_USER and SOME_PASS.
2. I run a command with the parameters: port = 12345, username = SOME_USER, password = SOME_PASS.
3. I can now connect another app to `localhost:12345` and effectively be using the remote SOCKS server.

I'm not that familiar with networking so I apologize if I got some terminology wrong here!

Comment: I've been searching around a bit and apparently authenticated socks servers are actually really uncommon.. TIL. Still hoping for a solution though!

Comment: which auth method and SOCKS version do you need?  WinGate supports taking a TCP connection and piping it through an upstream SOCKS4 server with SOCKS4 auth (just a password).